# The product of two repeating decimals

Tags: fractions, decimal-expansion

In [An exceptional talent for calculative thinking, (IML Hunter, 1962)](https://www.gwern.net/docs/psychology/1962-hunter.pdf), Professor Aitken explained how he found the decimal expansion of 1/851:

> 851 is 23 times 37. I use this fact as follows. 1/37 is 0.027027027027. . .. This I divide mentally by 23... 1/37 recurs at three places, 1/23 recurs at twenty-two places, the lowest common multiple of 3 and 22 is 66, whence I know that there is a recurring period of 66 places.’

I thought this is a general fact: two rationals with decimal periods a and b must have a decimal period of ab, but there is a clear counterexample:

$$0.\dot 2 \times 0.\dot 1 \dot 5 = 0.\dot{0}3367\dot{0}$$

So what is the general law?

Comment: Note:  in your counterexample, the denominators aren't relatively prime

Comment: did you mean they must have a decimal period of *the LCM of*... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule is that the product of two repeating decimals has period the least common multiple of their periods *provided the denominators are relatively prime* and the numerator of each fraction is relatively prime to the denominator of the other.

Comment: In your counterexample there is an extra factor of $3$ because $3$ divides both denominators

Comment: I think you may also need to require the numerator of each fraction to be relatively prime to the denominator of the other. For example, the period of $\frac{4}{33}$ is $2$, and the period of $\frac{11}{37}$ is $3$, but their product is $\frac{4}{111}$, which has period $3$, not $6$.

Comment: @quasi:  Thank you.  I agree and have edited my answer accordingly.  OP gave an example where the period is longer than the lcm, and you gave one where it's shorter

Comment: Is there a proof of this somewhere?

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate:  the period of $1/p$ is the order of $10$ modulo $p$, i.e., the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $10^k\equiv1\pmod p$; if $n$ is that order, then the solutions $k$ of $10^k\equiv1\pmod p$ are multiples of $n$ (i.e., $k=cn$, where $c$ is some integer) and no others; can you see how my claim then follows?